# How does “ghost pot” get its name

Tags: history

What is the history behind the name "ghost pot"? Why is it called "**ghost** pot"?

First, what is a ghost pot?

> Also known as a derelict crab trap, a ghost pot is a crab pot that has
>   lost its float and cannot be recovered by its owner.
>
> https://www.lafishblog.com/ghost-pots/

I surmised three possibilities.

1. Ghost is wandering and haunting. The ghost pot is also wandering around.
2. Ghost is someone who is dead.  The ghost pot is a pot which is dead because it cannot be used.
3. Ghost is scary. The ghost pot causes harm to marshes.

Comment: It's there but can't be seen by humans?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How would losing the buoy cause the trap to wander about? I believe crab pots are weighted so they sink to the bottom.

Comment: Likely it's a reference to the derelict ships that are called "ghost ships".  They just seem to appear out of the mist.

Comment: More to the point, why is it called a "pot" and not simply a "crab cage" or a "crab net"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ghost" is often used figuratively as a modifier to refer to things that are metaphorically dead compared to the normal version of the thing, just as a literal ghost is the dead version of a person.

Other examples are "ghost town" (a town that has been abandoned) and "ghost ship" (a boat with no crew or passengers).